# Реализация сводной таблицы

Tags: php, yii2

Есть такая задача: сводная таблица состоит из данных нескольких других таблиц. Они собираются, форматируются (например было в оригинале `$lastname, $firstname, $middlename` - собралось в один `$fullname` и т.п.) и выводятся на страницу в виде таблицы. Столбцов и строк довольно много.

В предыдущем проекте когда я делал такую же задачу я использовал [Dynagrid](http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid) для вывода и отдельную таблицу в которую я собирал все эти данные и из нее уже выводил их. Причем в отдельной таблице хранилась дата последнего обновления таблицы и через какое-то фиксированное время происходила очистка и новое заполнение этой таблицы (ну или если тыкнули спец. кнопочку "обновить таблицу").

Но мне это решение не особо понравилось. Во первых необходимость создавать для этого отдельную таблицу, структура которой кстати иногда меняется и в которой уж очень много столбцов (больше 10). Во вторых необходимость хранить отдельным полем время обновления и вручную проверять его. К тому же данные могли поменяться, а время обновлять таблицу еще не пришло...

Подскажите как такое кэширование будет реализовать правильнее? Данных действительно довольно много (например в районе 5к строк), но выводятся они само собой через пагинацию. Чем мне понравился именно этот грид - очень гибкий в настройке (например количество выводимых строк и отображаемые столбцы). Причем настраивать его может уже юзер под себя. Но можно и другой какой-нибудь использовать - не принципиально. Главное чтобы его было несложно встроить. Например рассматривал как альтернативу [JQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

Кажется никто не может понять что я имею ввиду, поэтому прикладываю полный код из старого проекта: [SummaryTable.php](https://pastebin.com/SXACvmm5), [SummaryTableManager.php](https://pastebin.com/9SsfGiQi), [index.php](https://pastebin.com/AgkFHE3C)

Comment: 5к это не много, семечки)

Comment: @Manitikyl все равно если их каждый раз заново подгружать из бд из разных таблиц и форматировать то загрузка страницы больше минуты занимает - что ни в какие ворота.

Comment: Надо смотреть что у вас там за запросы, если на 5к строк больше минуты, то скл не может быть, особенно если поиск индексированный, скорей просто память кушает. А по вашему вопросу, как-бы все расписали, но так абстрактно что вас не понять, вы должны знать что запросы в БД делаются через модели, так в чем проблема в самой модели объединять то что вам надо?

Comment: @Manitikyl не пойму что вам не ясно. Просто данные из разных таблиц тянутся. Например из таблицы `article` поля `name, status`, из таблицы `user_info` привязанной к таблице `user` привязанной к таблице `article` поля `lastname, firstname, middlename`, из таблицы `authors` тоже их имена и еще место работы, и т.д. Какая разница какие данные? Просто данные.

Comment: Сколько у вас релейшенов/джоинов? Вы используете **with** или **joinWith**? Они тянутся с помощью **eagerLoading**?

Comment: @Ninazu да джоинов много, но вот этого что вы сказали нету. Я даже не знаю что это...

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail
У вас на каждую сточку таблицы идёт как минимум один отдельный запрос)) Гляньте в Debug, ну либо поверьте просто на слово, отсюда и скорость. Нужно вытаскивать все необходимые данные сразу. Форматировать можно прям на стороне MySQL например так `SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname), ... `

Comment: @Ninazu нет у меня отдельного запроса на каждую строчку. Скорее уж отдельный запрос (а то и не один) на каждый столбец.

Comment: https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-active-record/#lazy-eager-loading

Comment: Возможно как альтернативу можно просто закэшировать всю страницу средствами кэширования Yii? Вот только потянет ли оно так много данных? Да еще этот грид с разными поисками и сортировками...

Answer (score -1):

> @Ninazu нет у меня отдельного запроса на каждую строчку. Скорее уж отдельный запрос (а то и не один) на каждый столбец.

Я бы не был так категоричен. Вот пример без **with**

```
$articles = Article::find()
    //->with(['user']) //Раскомментировать вконце
    ->limit(2)
    ->all();

//Cмотрим вытащились релейшены для первой записи?
print_r(array_keys($articles[0]->getRelatedRecords()));

//Обращаемся к релейшену
$articles[0]->user->user_id;

//Перепроверим релейшены, после первого обращения
print_r(array_keys($articles[0]->getRelatedRecords()));

//Ну и если вы думаете что оно подтянуло релейшены для всех строк, то это можно проверить так
print_r(array_keys($articles[1]->getRelatedRecords()));
```

Comment: Вы пишите какой-то абстрактный код в вакууме. Вы подумайте лучше о том как вы это выводить будете на страницу? Модель должна быть одна чтобы ее можно было вывести. И если честно я не понимаю как эти with ваши работают и то что вы называете релейшенами. Я умею только в обычные sql-джоины.

Comment: Ну тогда не помешал бы пример вашего кода. Как вы используете модели и как их передаете в DynaGrid, потому что это не мой код абстрактный, а ваш вопрос

Comment: Используете вы **SqlDataProvider**, или **ActiveDataProvider**? То вы с моделями работаете, то с SQL. Вы бы определились прежде чем минусовать ответы, и почитали бы документацию по Yii2 и разобрались как что работает

Comment: Добавил в вопрос исходники

Comment: @DarkByte Можете скинуть query который передается в **ActiveDataProvider ** в **SummaryTable::search**, и засечь время на формирование этого query померять

Comment: Если вы о том `$query` который в начале передается в `ActiveDataProvider` то его легко проследить до `SummaryTableManager::compute`. Весь код выложен. Нет разве что `$this->contest->getSummaryTables()`, но там все тривиально `$this->hasMany(SummaryTable::class, ['contest_id' => 'id'])`. Собственно этот самый `compute` и занимает больше всего времени.

Comment: Но вы не в ту сторону копаете! Я же сразу сказал что этот способ плохой. Я хочу от него уйти, а не улучшать. Мне нужна свежая идея.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80062/discussion-between-ninazu-and-dark-byte).